# Is this safe? Is this OK to do in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, unix, backup

I have always done this:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uuser -ppass MYDATABASE > /home/f/db_backup/MYDATABASE.sql
mysql -uuser -ppass MYDATABASE < MYDATABASE.sql
```

But, if I do this instead...is this safe? Is this identical to the above???

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uuser -ppass MYDATABASE | gzip > /home/f/db_backup/MYDATABASE.sql.gz
zcat MYDATABASE.sql.gz | mysql -uuser -ppass MYDATABASE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's totally fine (and more efficient, of course!) Mysql doesn't see any difference; both methods end up passing uncompressed SQL data.

Comment: Ok, if my data is lost, you owe me 50 million dollars

Comment: If you are risking 50 million dollars worth of data on the answer to a SO question, you owe your boss 50 million dollars.

Comment: If you do lose the data, it'll probably be something out of manual control like power failure/data corruption, that won't be caused by gzipping the data.

Comment: 50 million dollars? Your data is totally safe at the special file `/dev/null`. Even a crash doesn't change the contents of that file :)

Comment: Thanks all :) Nahh my data is worth like 5 dollars.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe (mostly) and if you had spare CPU cycles you could add '-C' to
your mysqldump to have it compress client <-> server comms which should save 
you some time on large DBs. 
FWIW per db username/password details in ~/.my.cnf of the user who is running
the mysqldump command.  This way the DB credentials won't be viewable by other 
users on the system using command like 'ps'.